# Unity web player doesn't support the C# BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webdeploy

I have a game where stored the score and after login it load the score from binaryFormatter C# but it clearly run in unity editor and another platforms but it cannot work on unity web player. My .unity3D file has upload on google drive and share with everyone and can edit anyone and the .html file is on WEEBLY web online host with embed code.

So I want to ask that, is there anyway to store value and load the value without use playerpref and binaryFormatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform HTTP GET/POST request using the `WWW` class and send data along.

```
WWW www = new WWW("http://www.domain.com/send_score.php?user=23&score=42");
```

You can also retrieve data.

```
WWW www = new WWW("http://www.domain.com/get_score.php?user=23"); // The response body is an integer.
yield return www;
int score = (int)www.text;
```

Be aware that this is not secure. Anyone who knows the URL can inject fake data just performing the request (via a browser for instance). Maybe some cryptography technique can help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes there is!

I'm not sure I understood your question, you want to save the score locally or on a server?

To send your object over network, you need to:

1.Make an array of bytes,
You can use other types of serialization like Google's ProtoBuf and JSON. If it's just one simple score, you can just change it to string, no need for serialization. The important part is that you have a way to change your object to a series of bytes and vice versa. (Serialization and Deserialization)

2.Send your data over simple TCP connections, or in more high-level ways like HTTP-POST request. And in doing so make sure your transfer is secure.

If you want to just hold the score in the device (locally), you can serialize the data and write them to a file, or you can use Sqlite to use lite databases locally. You can use some security to prevent data tampering. In your case I think SOOMLA framework is a good solution.